# Change the text from DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```html
<label class="checkbox-1">
 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Add
</label>
```

How to change the text "Add", with java script? Note: I don't want to delete the checkbox, only to change the text.

Comment: Could you provide some information about the Javascript you have tried?

Comment: @glend, `document.querySelector('.checkbox-1').innerHTML = "TEST";`, but this will delete the whole html from label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add id attr to the html and use the following JavaScript code:

```js
var selector = document.getElementById('someText');
selector.lastChild.textContent = 'hiiiiiiiii';
```

```html
<label id="someText" class="checkbox-1">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="" > Add
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want to do this in native javascript or another external library; like JQuery. Assuming native javascript, it can be done like so:

```js
document.getElementById("checkbox1").textContent= "<modifiedtext>" ;
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-1">
 <input class="checkbox" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Add
</label>
```

Notice the new id to make searching and variablising the dom element easier. Ideally DOM manipulation is better done in JQuery. At least from my experience.

Comment: I don't believe this would work. Changing the text content of the checkbox input won't change the "Add" text, as that belongs to the label rather than the input.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer that I contributed did not target the main problem. So because the label text exists as a parent of the input we need to go through another way.
I have posted a snippet using JQuery.

```
// find elements
var checkbox = $("#checkbox1")
var labelCheckbox = $("#checkbox1").parent('label')

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    checkbox.text('New')
    labelCheckbox.text('Hello')
});**strong text**
```

Once the document is loaded, it will change the text by finding the parent element of the input type which we assume is the label and then change the text.